# Error from Python job scheduling module each time I stop server

Tags: python, django

My models.py file in my Django project contains the code based on the [following tutorial](https://github.com/dbader/schedule):

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
        print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Each time I run the application, I get the following output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python27\python.exe D:/blogpodapi/manage.py runserver 8000
I'm working...
I'm working...
```

It works as expected, but whenever I close the application, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/blogpodapi/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\blogpodapi\blogpodapi\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Further to this, my server does not start... as when I remove the abovementioned code, I get the following output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python27\python.exe D:/blogpodapi/manage.py runserver 8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 14, 2016 - 14:00:32
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'blogpodapi.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

I am not to sure what is causing this error. The server won't start when the scheduler is in place and there is an error each time I try to stop the server when it is in place. Ideally I would like the server to start as expected, and the scheduled tasks to start running after this. Any recommendations on how I can fix this?

The entirety of the models.py file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/0DwQWqM8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any problem.

The Traceback you posted reports a KeyboardInterrupt which is commonly used to force-quit an application and thus completely normal.

The server also seems to have started.
Have you tried visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/ while the server is running?
The last line just tells you to use CTRL-C in the command line if you want to stop the server.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to suppress the error message? I tried going to the server but it didn't appear to be running. Normally I get a message in the terminal telling me that it has started. What I think is happening is that the periodic task starts running and because it is set to run indefinitely, it stops the server from starting.

Comment: I've just tried it now and can confirm that visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/ returns a `This site can’t be reached` message.